# Proper selector for this tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I cant seem to find the right jquery selector for this tag:

HTML:

```
<div class="span4 span4-mod">
    <div class="well well-mod">
    <h4 class="DomainDescription">Iniz LAX1</h4>
    <span class="btn-block">
        <button></button>
    </span>
    <form action="pinfo.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" value="">
        <button>History</button>    
    </form>
    Port Status<br />
    <span class="portstatus porton">21</span>
    <table class="table" style="margin-top: 10px;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Distro:</strong></td>
                <td class="showdistro">Debian 7.1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Online since: </strong></td>
                <td class="showonline">2 Days 10:29</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>    
</div>
```

I'm trying to search for the class "DomainDescription", and then search for the HTML within the class "showonline", and manipulate the latter.

I'm looking for the relationship of sibling (table) >child (tbody) > child (tr) > child (td)

Try as I may, I cant seem to find a proper selector for this kind of relationship.

I began by:

```
$('.DomainDescription').each(function () {                  
    var PrintedUptime=$(this).siblings().children(".showonline").html();
    alert (PrintedUptime);
});
```

What should the proper selector be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can

```
$('.DomainDescription').each(function () {                  
    var PrintedUptime=$(this).closest('.well-mod').find(".showonline").html();
    alert (PrintedUptime);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/p2Ggj/)

Comment: That's awesome. I didnt know I could do that!

Answer (score 0):

The correct css selector is:

```
.DomainDescriptor~table>tbody>tr>td>.showonline
```

I think that is correct, at least. Therefore, you can use:

```
$('.DomainDescriptor~table>tbody>tr>td>.showonline').each(function(){
    alert(this.html());
})
```

to achieve the desired effect. This is not tested.